Use of id_token returned by code exchange when using 'Sign in with Google'
I'm following these instructions to implement 'Sign in with Google' for my site.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server
And it's all working great.
However I'm not sure what I should be doing with the id_token.
In "Step 5: Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens", it says:
"The response contains the following fields: access_token, expires_in, refresh_token, scope, and token_type".
Which it indeed does. However, it also contains id_token.
It seems I can get the email address of the user, in order to find out who has signed into my site, in one of two ways:

Call https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo with the access_token
Call GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify with the id_token.

Should I be doing one, the other, or both of these?
If both, should I verify the email address from each matches? Is there a potential vector for it not to match, and what's the implication thereof?
I use GoogleIdTokenVerifier in a different app to verify the user when I only have an id_token that they have generated client-side using gcloud auth print-identity-token, and I can see the point of it there - as the id_token there is effectively user input, but what I'm talking about here is a web server that knows the id_token has come from Google as it has just done the code exchange, so it seems a bit pointless to need to verify it with Google again.
So is it good enough for authentication purposes to just call https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo with the access_token?
Can I rely on the id_token being in the response from oauth2.googleapis.com/token, even though it doesn't list it in the response fields in the linked doc?
Does GoogleIdTokenVerifier actually do a network request to let Google look up the token in its database, or does it just parse it locally? I'm tempted to believe it does a network request as I pass it a NetHttpTransport in its constructor, but would welcome confirmation.
Thanks

The id token is used in token-based authentication to cache user profile information and provide it to a client application.
If you take your id token and place it in jwt.io you will see that it contains basic profile information about the user.
So if you want to know who the user is you use the id token thats really all its used for.

That leaves me still slightly confused about how the id token verifier works. I'm still not sure whether it verifies it by making a network request to Google itself, or by simply parsing the contents. The latter implies to me that it could potentially be reverse engineered
And would it be possible for someone to 'spoof' an id_token - so for example could someone construct an id_token for a different user  who they're trying to impersonate using jwt.io?

Signature validation will need a network call to get to the discovery doc followed by the certs to verify the ID token signature. You can read more about what goes on for ID token validation here - https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#validatinganidtoken. It is always the RP's responsibility to verify an ID token before using its contents.

See https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token on how to verify ID token.
